# Content inside bootstrap Modal does not get padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a modal that i open in my project, Some CSS modifications are not displayed.
This is my code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal ">
       <div class="form-group ">
            <label class="control-label resetPasswordPadding">Reset Password</label>
            <label class="control-label resetPasswordPadding">Enter your login name, and we will email you a link to reset your password</label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control input-xs" id="loginName" required ng-model="inputPassword" >
            <button ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="cancel()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>

            <button ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="sendResetLink()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Link Reset</button>
       </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The CSS i use is:

```
.resetPasswordPadding {
padding: 5px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

And it does not have effect on the content, If i put a css like:

```
.resetPasswordRemoveBold {
font-weight: normal;
```

}
And change the Reset password label as:

```
<label class="control-label resetPasswordRemoveBold">Reset Password</label>
```

It will set normal text, so why not setting padding / margin ?

My goal is to make a Forgot my password form inside a modal, but i must control the margin/padding etc, When i use chrome debugger, i can see my margin/padding is 0, it did not override the default.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're confident that the CSS file is actually being loaded, whatever rule is setting the padding at 0 probably has higher precedence than your `.resetPasswordPadding` class.

Either increase the precedence:

```
form div.form-group label.resetPasswordPadding { padding:5px }
```

Or add !important to the rule:

```
.resetPasswordPadding { padding:5px !important }
```

It's generally best practice to increase precedence rather than overusing `!important`